# shell script fails when executed by cronjob, works fine otherwise

Tags: java, linux, shell, cron, executable-jar

I have an executable jar and I have written a shell script to execute it. When I run the shell script manually, it runs fine but when schedule to run it weekly using crontab, it gives the following error -

```
log_process.sh: line 16: java: command not found
```

Line 16 in my shell script is -

```
java -jar $jar_path $logDirectory $logNamePattern $processedLogDirectory $oldResultsDirectory 2>>$log_file 1>&2
```

Any idea why is it happening that it runs fine when I run it manually but not when it gets run by vrontab job?

Comment: which command do you fire while running manually and which one while using cron job?

Comment: 1. is it the same user? 2. if yes, is the environment the same? Hint: try and `env` in cron and at the command line

Comment: Where is your java installed. Try with the full path to your java installation. For example /usr/local/bin/java -jar $har_path...

Comment: And also make sure that $jar_path is the full path to your jar file.

Comment: I think this is your case: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224969/shell-script-not-running-via-crontab-runs-fine-manually?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224969/shell-script-not-running-via-crontab-runs-fine-manually?rq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your cron job doesn't have access to the same $PATH variable that you as a user have.

The easiest way to fix this is to open up a terminal, and run this command:

```
which java
```

That's going to give you the absolute path of your java executable.  For example:

```
/opt/Oracle/Java/bin/java
```

Replace your 'java' command with the whole path.

You might also want to specify the JAVA_HOME variable in your shell script.
From your terminal run:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

That'll give you another path, like '/opt/Oracle/Java'.  In your script (assuming you are using bash), before you run the java command, put:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/Oracle/Java
```

Replacing '/opt/Oracle/Java' with the output that the previous echo gave you.

Comment: sorry..my bad...its executing by doing what you told me...its some other problem about which i m not sure..thanks for help..

Comment: Well, even if this is answered, give me more information to see if I can help :D